# Allow users to see each other's data in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Is there a why to let two user login with their own email and password and see the same data?

(Maybe one user well login and be transferred to the other user that has all the data).

Thanks,
Zvi Karp

Comment: should they be able to see the data at the same time?

Comment: yes, I don't what to copy all the data (I what to have 10 users that can all see the same data).

Answer (score 1):

What you were trying to do is about [Database Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design), it's actually not about Firebase. (watch out: the link is about ***relational database*** design, but Firebase is not using relational database. The idea is the same though.)

There are many ways to achieve your goal. Since you didn't describe your question clearly, I'll just give a general solution:

1. add a key `sahredData` to your `User` entity, and the value of this key is the `id` of the data you want to share between users. Different users can use the same value in this field(which means they share the same data).
2. whenever a user needs to access the shared data, use the value of `sharedData`, which is the `id` of the shared data, to access the data.

Comment: All cool! but what about authentication? In your solution the sheared file well be public. Can I use Firebase rules? Do you have a demo? Thanks!

Comment: The permission is another thing. The file will not be public if you set the permission correctly. And, yes, of course you can use the rules.